# put default data to edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Get data from edittext e_1, e_2 to sum up those things, but it rarely put those things together. For instance, I wrote 0 in e_1, and 1 in e_2, pref KEY says '1', but when I wrote nothing in e_1, and 1 in e_2, it makes error and down. So although he/she wrote nothing in e_1, it also have to put '0' in a. What I Have TO DO?

```
a = Integer.parseInt(e_1.getText().toString());
b = Integer.parseInt(e_2.getText().toString());

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_time.edit();
editor.putInt(KEY, a+b));
editor.commit();
```

Comment: e_1.getText().toString() returns null when edittext is empty which cause error in your code

Comment: Put 0 by default in your edittext to overcome this error

Comment: check the editext by  TextUtils.isEmpty(e_1.getText().toString()) if it is empty than it return true. so after checking that edittext  is empty or not  you can do what you want..

Comment: you need to check weather edit text empty or not  first,  like :
===>  
 b = Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(e_2.getText().toString()) ? "0" : e_2.getText().toString() );   <===

Comment: So how I put 0 in my edittext? by android:hint? or something?

Comment: just keep above mentioned condition for both of  'a' and 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `e_2` is empty, in this line:

```
b = Integer.parseInt(e_2.getText().toString());
```

you will get an error because `e_2.getText().toString()` returns empty string, and it can't be parsed to `Integer`.

You have to check if it is empty first:

```
String aText = e_1.getText().toString();
String bText = e_2.getText().toString();

a = TextUtils.isEmpty(aText)? 0 : Integer.parseInt(aText);
b = TextUtils.isEmpty(bText)? 0 : Integer.parseInt(bText);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out**

```
String editText1=e_1.getText().toString().trim();
String editText2=e_1.getText().toString().trim();

if((editText1!= null || !editText1.equals("")) && (editText2!=null || !editText2.equals("")))
{
        a = Integer.parseInt(editTextData1);
        b = Integer.parseInt(editTextData2);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_time.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY, a+b));
        editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when edittext is empty it return null to `e_1.getText().toString()` so first check if edittext is empty or not like this :

```
String editTextData1 = e_1.getText().toString().trim();
String editTextData2 = e_1.getText().toString().trim();
```

`trim();` is to avoid blank spaces and then check like this to avoid any Exception :

```
if(editTextData1!="" || editTextData2!=""){
    a = Integer.parseInt(editTextData1);
    b = Integer.parseInt(editTextData2);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_time.edit();
    editor.putInt(KEY, a+b));
    editor.commit();
}
```